# Firebase, cant get instance ID token (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I need the instance ID token(or registration token) associated with my app to validate an A/B testing experiment on a test device . I have tried using the following code mentioned in the Firebase docs, but that hasnt helped me so far.

```
    Firebase.InstanceId.FirebaseInstanceId.DefaultInstance.GetTokenAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
if (!(task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted) && task.IsCompleted) {
  UnityEngine.Debug.Log(System.String.Format("Instance ID Token {0}", task.Result));
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you've solved this, but I'd recommend breaking out the error check (isCanceled || isFaulted), into its own condition so that you can log out the actual error. Right now you're logging if it DOES work, but not the actual error if it DOESN'T, which is precisely the information you want to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Coroutine did the job for me:

```
private IEnumerator Start () 
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> t = Firebase.InstanceId.FirebaseInstanceId.DefaultInstance.GetTokenAsync();
    while (!t.IsCompleted) yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Debug.Log(" FirebaseID is " + t.Result);

}
```

Also note that...

> IsCompleted will return true when the task is in one of the three final states: RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled.

according to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted?view=netframework-4.7.1). So no need to test all three states.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Firebase versions for Unity use the following

```
string installationId = await FirebaseInstallations.DefaultInstance.GetIdAsync(); // Most likely this is your case
string installationId = await FirebaseInstallations.GetInstance(app).GetIdAsync(); // Option 2 with particular app
Debug.Log(" FirebaseID is " + installationId);
```